# Image file was not found while fetching image of products in magento

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to fetch image of product but magento showing error image file was not found

```
There has been an error processing your request
Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile(NULL)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/whi/brand/my_collections/brand_indi_collection_view.phtml(98): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'thumbnail')
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/X...')
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/whohasitadmin/layout/admin.phtml(224): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/Applications/X...')
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#19 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/local/Whi/Brands/controllers/MycollectionController.php(358): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#20 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Whi_Brands_MycollectionController->individual_collection_viewAction()
#21 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('individual_coll...')
#22 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}

Error log record number: 1154029962119
```

This is my controller.

```
public function individual_collection_viewAction() {

        $Params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();

        $category->load($Params['id']);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $data['products'] = $collection->load();

        $this->loadLayout();

        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('mycollection_individual_view');

        if ($block) {
            $block->setData($data);

        }
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

And this is my view:

```
    <?php 
                                        foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
                                          $productName = $product->getName();
                                          $proimage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
                                          //$productImage = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, true) . "media/catalog/product" .$product->getImage();
?>
```

Products name successfully fetched but when i trying to get image it's goes to re image was not found. Can anyone help me to resolve my this issue.

Comment: try this `$product->getImage(); //getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()`

Comment: Sathish, it's showing this error   Fatal error: Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/whi/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/whi/brand/my_collections/brand_indi_collection_view.phtml on line 99

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First You need to verify the base, small and thumbnail image are selected in Magento admin.

admin->catalog->manage product->product->image

Then you call the image using

```
$proimage = (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');//image,smallimage
```

or

```
$proimage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail()); //getSmallImage(), getImage()
```

**Edit:**

```
foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
     $productName = $product->getName();
     $proimage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
    }
```

Comment: Sathish i check image is stored in magento admin panel also i check image on this path http://localhost/abc/media/catalog/product/s/h/shoes.jpg. image file is existing. i used your code but still image file was not found error occurred.

Comment: I updated my answer check & let me know `$product->getName();` is working mean `getThumbnail()` also working fine, try var_dump($product); if you see thumbnail it will display

Comment: Sathish, it's work for one product, i surprised when i added your update code, it display image of one product only, other product images not showing, but now no image found error not occurred what i missing again :-(

Comment: or even i remove that image which is showing, but after removed it still displaying in only against one product

Comment: It's goes to that url: http://localhost/whi/media/catalog/product/  not goes to proper URL

Comment: if you change any thing in backend once clear cache and try

Comment: once you conform all the products have selected thumbnails else use condition to check if thumbnail or show placeholder image

Comment: Sathish, i check but now not placeholder image display or not product image, when i inspect the image url: http://localhost/whi/media/catalog/product/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88157/discussion-between-sathish-and-muhammad-awais).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach ($data['products'] as $product) { 
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$productName = $product->getName();
$proimage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
?>
```

Comment: Dear Alex, thanks for reply. It's showing placeholder image not product image.